# Cufon not showing up in firefox and opera?

Tags: html, wordpress, cufon

The cufon doesn't work in firefox and opera, but works fine in safari/IE and chrome.
http://www.pixocasa.com/video/

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the domain of your cufon source different to that of your site? Firefox has a a strict same origin policy that prevents loading of some things if they are on different domains